# Dúvida com relacionamento de tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, relacionamento

Boa noite tenho o seguinte BD em MySQL

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cad_cliente` (
      `id_cliente` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `nome_cliente` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `nome_dr` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `email_cliente` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `data_nascimento_cliente` date NOT NULL,
      `endereco_cliente` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `bairro_cliente` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `cep_cliente` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `cidade_cliente` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `estado_cliente` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `observacao` varchar(45) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cad_paciente` (
     `id_paciente` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `nome_paciente` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `id_cliente` varchar(45) NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cad_trabalho` (
     `id_trabalho` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `id_cliente` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `id_paciente` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `id_dente` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `id_servico` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `id_cor` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `observacao_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `data_entrada_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `data_saida_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `pronto_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `valor_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `pagamento_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `foto1_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `foto2_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `foto3_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Gostaria de saber como fazer para exibir uma consulta ao banco de dados via PHP para que ao solicitar a uma página que me mostre os dados da tabela `cad_trabalho`, essa solicitação busque os dados de nome do paciente e do cliente no banco de dados.

Comment: Você quer "exibir" uma consulta ou precisa de ajuda para criar a consulta? (como faço para exibir uma consulta)...Você ja tentou criar esta consulta ou não sabe por onde começar?

Comment: Bom noite @PauloRoberto, eu sei fazer de uma forma que teria que criar varias veses o seguinte comando `$trabalho = mysql_query("select * from cad_trabalho where id_trabalho='".$id_trabalho."'");` e `$cliente = mysql_query("select * from cad_cliente where id_cliente='".$id_cliente."'");` e `$paciente = mysql_query("select * from cad_paciente where id_paciente='".$id_paciente."'");` andei pesquisando sobre relacionamentos das tabelas que tem uma maneira mais simples de se fazer essa consulta ai nao sei por onde começar

Comment: e para exibir teria que fazer da seguinte forma

`while($C = mysql_fetch_array($cliente)) {
 $nome_cliente     = $V["nome_cliente"];`

`while($P = mysql_fetch_array($paciente)) {
 $nome_paciente     = $V["nome_paciente"];`

`while($T = mysql_fetch_array($trabalho)) {
 $id_trabalho     = $V["nome_trabalho"];`

Assim por diante para receber todos os dados necessarios

Comment: @CristianoCardosoSilva Utilize o campo de resposta abaixo para apresentar soluções, aqui é para pedir sugestões ou sugerir melhorias

Comment: Bom noite @MaiconCarraro estou apenas informando para o Paulo Roberto como eu faço hoje minhas solicitações

Comment: Sim, eu entendo, mas aqui é mt curto o campo

Answer (score 3):

Você não especificou se sua dúvida é na montagem do `SELECT` ou na construção do código `PHP`, então vamos por partes:

### SQL

(Utilizando `INNER JOIN` para relacionar as tabelas)

```
SELECT observacao_trabalho, nome_cliente, nome_paciente 
FROM cad_trabalho 
INNER JOIN cad_cliente ON cad_cliente.id_cliente = cad_trabalho.id_cliente 
INNER JOIN cad_paciente ON cad_paciente.id_paciente = cad_trabalho.id_paciente
```

### PHP

(Exemplo apenas didático)

```
<?php
    $servidor = "localhost"; /* exemplo */
    $usuarioBanco = "root"; /* exemplo */
    $senhaBanco = "123456"; /* exemplo */
    $nomeBanco = "exemplo"; /* exemplo */

    /* mysqli é o que você utiliza para fazer conexão com o banco */
    $conn = new mysqli($servidor, $usuarioBanco, $senhaBanco, $nomeBanco);

    $sql = "SELECT observacao_trabalho, nome_cliente, nome_paciente FROM cad_trabalho INNER JOIN cad_cliente ON cad_cliente.id_cliente = cad_trabalho.id_cliente INNER JOIN cad_paciente ON cad_paciente.id_paciente = cad_trabalho.id_paciente";

    /* resultado da consulta */
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    /* verifica se retornou algo */
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        /* começa a construir a tabela no HTML */
        echo "<table><tr><th>Trabalho</th><th>Cliente</th><th>Paciente</th></tr>";

        /* percorre o retorno da consulta */
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            /* dentro do $row[] vai o nome da coluna da sua consulta */
            echo "<tr><td>".$row["observacao_trabalho"]."</td><td>".$row["nome_cliente"]." ".$row["nome_paciente"]."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "Nenhum resultado encontrado";
    }

    /* fecha conexão */
    $conn->close();
?>
```

### Considerações

- [Diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/6448#6448)
- [PHP e MySQL para iniciantes](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/php-e-mysql-para-iniciantes-consulta-simples/)

Comment: testei aqui mas nao busca as informaçoes no banco de dados e ainda gera um erro
`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\lista_servicos.php on line 18
Nenhum resultado encontrado`

Comment: Ai o erro esta nessa função 
         if ($result->num_rows > 0)

Answer (score 0):

testei aqui mas nao busca as informaçoes no banco de dados e ainda gera um erro

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\lista_servicos.php on line 18 Nenhum resultado encontrado
```

Ai o erro esta nessa função

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia meus amigos,
com as dicas dos nossos amiso aqui consegui resolver meu select que ficou assim

```
SELECT * FROM cad_trabalho
JOIN  cad_paciente ON cad_trabalho.id_paciente
JOIN  cad_cliente ON cad_paciente.id_cliente WHERE cad_trabalho.id_trabalho=1
```

Agora so falta eu montar o php para exibir os resultados